# bash script to assign value to a variable in for loop

Tags: bash, shell, slurm

I'm trying to submit each batch job in a different directory, i.e, .test1/, .test2/, .test3/. So I iterate over the ./test* directories and set the variable $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR, which controls the directory where I submit the job.

```
#!/bin/bash -l
# script.sh

DIRS="./test*/"

for dir in  $DIRS
do
  export $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR =$dir
  echo $dir
  sbatch submitfile
done
```

Here comes the result:

`` script.sh: line 9: export: `=./test1scan/': not a valid identifier
./test1scan/
Submitted batch job 312892
script.sh: line 9: export: `=./test2scan/': not a valid identifier
./test2scan/
Submitted batch job 312893
script.sh: line 9: export: `=./test3scan/': not a valid identifier
./test3scan/
Submitted batch job 312894 ``

EDITED:
Thanks to Chepner, the error disappears. However, the job was submitted in the directory where I run this bash script. Is there any way to submit each job in different directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put a space after the equal sign in an argument to `export`:

```
export "$SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR=$dir"
```

Comment: deleted the space but still the same error :(

Comment: What's the value of `SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR`? Or is that the name of the variable you want to set? In that case, you need to drop the `$`, that is, `export "SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR=$dir"`.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works with no errors. But the job was not submitted in different directory....

Comment: Are you looking for the `-D` option to `sbatch`?

Comment: Yes! Finally figure out that -D can be used in command line as well!

Comment: By the way, why do we use double quotes in export?

Comment: Not so much for `export`, but to protect the parameter expansions. Consider something like `foo="hello world"; export bar=$foo`. Without the quotes, you would export a variable `bar` with the value "hello", and another unset variable named `world`. `export "bar=$foo"` ensures a single, space-containing value for `bar`. Also, `export bar="$foo"` would work just as well; I just tend to quote long blocks of text where possible.